# Is it possible to use multiple separator parameters in python using .split()?

Tags: python, string, split

I need to break down a string into 3 chunks, (Example: ABC123DEF would end up as X=ABC Y=123 Z=DEF) and need some assistance in getting the alphabetical parts to not be combined into X=ABCDEF as apposed to separate items.

Comment: And what is the rule of splitting?

Comment: you can just treat your string as an array of letters and do "X=" + string[0:3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.split` by `\d+` and use grouping to keep the splitting-text.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = 'ABC123DEF'
>>> re.split('(\d+)', s)
['ABC', '123', 'DEF']
```